# How to query nested object in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm new to mongodb and I've been trying to query this doc for awhile now.

Im trying to query all the rooms that have a room **name** of **100**.

**json**

```
{
"count": 3,
"reviews": [
    {
        "_id": "5f9d42a0a8e71e004643f584",
        "user": {
            "_id": "5f7308cde0a4a7a66bc3d184",
            "name": "Guest"
        },
        "room": {
            "_id": "5f98f9321fd5bb0045b3d886",
            "name": "100",
        },
        "rating": 4,
    },
    {
        "_id": "5f9d431ea8e71e004643f585",
        "user": {
            "_id": "5f7308cde0a4a7a66bc3d184",
            "name": "Guest",
        },
        "room": {
            "_id": "5f98f9321fd5bb0045b3d886",
            "name": "100",
        },
        "rating": 5,
    },
    {
        "_id": "5f9e74fea6c06a0046d3cae2",
        "user": {
            "_id": "5f7308cde0a4a7a66bc3d184",
            "name": "Guest",
        },
        "room": {
            "_id": "5f98fa8b1fd5bb0045b3d88a",
            "name": "300",
        },
        "rating": 5,   
    }
]}
```

what I've tried

```
1. find({},{"reviews.room.name": {$eq: "100"}}) // getting a projection error
2. find({"reviews.room.name": "100"}) // getting null
```

Any help to the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `find({"reviews": { $elemMatch:{"room.name": "100"} } })`

Comment: I'm getting an empty array as the response

Comment: Are you sure? It works as it should: https://mongoplayground.net/p/iiBj8hITbPB

Comment: Thanks for your effort.But I've already found a solution.I think my problem was confusing the mongo-db structure. The reviews was my own created object my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the docs about how to use find:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

and try this

```
db.reviews.find({
  "room.name": "100"
})
```

Here is the playground with your example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/dPfH5fSOePq

Comment: Thanks this works. I think I was confusing the mongo-db structure.

Comment: I'm glad if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

did u try this ? const response = await Room.find({name: "100"})